# Given a fixed (but non-linear) calendar of future equipment usage; how to calculate the life at a given date in time

Tags: t-sql

I have a challenge that i'm really struggling with.

I have a table which contains a 'scenario' that a user has defined, that they will consume 'usage'. For example, how many hours a machine will be turned on for.

In month 1, they will use 300 (hours, stored as an integer in minutes), Month 2 100, Month 3 450 etc etc etc.

I then have a list of tasks which need to be performed at specific intervals of usage. Given the above scenario, how could I forecast when these tasks will be due (the date). I also need to show repeat accomplishments and the dates.

The task contains the number of consumed hours at the last point of accomplishment, the interval between accomplishments and the expected life total the next time it is due (Last Done + Interval = Next Due)

I've tried SO many different options, ideally I want this to be compiled at run time (i.e. the only things that are saved into a permanent table are the forecast and the list of tasks). I have 7-800 scenarios, plus given the number of pieces of equipment, there are 12,000 tasks to be carried out. I need to show at least the next 100 years of tasks.

At the minute, I get the scenario, cross apply a list of dates between now and the year 2118. I then (in the where clause) filter out where the period number (the month number of the year) isn't matching the date, then divide the period usage by the number of days in that period. That gives me a day to day usage over the next 100 years (~36,000 Rows) When I join on the 12000 tasks and then try to filter where the due at value matches my dates table, I can't return ANY rows, even just the date column and the query runs for 7-8 minutes.

We measure more than just hours of usage too, there are 25 different measurement points, all of which are specificed in the scenario.

I can't use linear regression, because lets say for example, we shut down over the summer, and we don't utilize the equipment, then an average usage over the year means that tasks are due, even when we are telling the scenario we're shut down.

Are there any strategies out there that I could apply. I'm not looking for a 'Here's the SQL' answer, I'm just running out of strategies to form a solid query that can deal with the volume of data I'm dealing with.

I can get a query running perfectly with one task, but it just doesn't scale... at all...

If SQL isn't the answer, then i'm open to suggestions.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: This is way to broad for stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], specifically [ask].

Comment: Any recommendations of places to ask? I'm very lost 

Comment: Here on Stackoverflow you are supposed to ask very specific questions, with a narrow scope. If you can narrow the scope of your question, you might get an answer here. Please note that good questions contains a [mcve]. In sql, that translates into sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert into statements) for sample data, and desired results. Your current question might be a better fit to an SQL development forum.